# Rails: stylesheet path in js file on production

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my js file I have some configs like

```
skel.init({
        reset: 'full',
        containers: '100%',
        breakpoints: {
            global: { href: '/assets/skel/style.scss', grid: { gutters: ['2.5em', 0] } },
            xlarge: { media: '(max-width: 1800px)', href: '/assets/skel/style-xlarge.scss' },
            large: { media: '(max-width: 1280px)', href: '/assets/skel/style-large.scss', grid: { gutters: ['2em', 0] } },
            medium: { media: '(max-width: 980px)', href: '/assets/skel/style-medium.scss'},
            small: { media: '(max-width: 736px)', href: '/assets/skel/style-small.scss', grid: { gutters: ['1.5em', 0] }, viewport: { scalable: false } },
            xsmall: { media: '(max-width: 480px)', href: '/assets/skel/style-xsmall.scss' }
        }
    });
```

as you can see there are `href`s for css files like `href: '/assets/skel/style.scss'` which contain in `app/assets/stylesheets/skel` directory. In development it works perfect, but on production assets compiling and js can't find those css files.

I tried to add `config.assets.precompile += ['skel/*']` to `production.rb` to compile `skel` assets to `skel` directory but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `.erb` extension to your javascript file, you can use `asset_path` helpers inside javascript which will be expanded properly on assets precompile. For example, make your javascript file to be `some_filename.js.erb`, then inside, you can set up paths to CSS like this:

```
global: { href: '<%= stylesheet_path "skel/style" %>', grid: { gutters: ['2.5em', 0] } }
```

and so on...

For reference, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_path to figure out how `stylesheet_path` expands.